# split() and parseInt

Tags: java, android

After creating a string with

```
String data = String.valueOf(seekBar1.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar2.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar3.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar4.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar5.getProgress());
```

sending this String to another device over bluetooth, and then using

```
byte[] rBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String rMessage = new String(rBuf);
String[] split = rMessage.split(":");
seekBar1.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
seekBar2.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
seekBar3.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
seekBar4.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(split[3]));
seekBar5.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(split[4]));
```

I get

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0�������������"...
```

I know what the exception is, but I am not completely sure why it is being thrown, I have printed the received number as a String and as far as I can see *only* the integer is present in split[4]..

Any ideas what is going on here? Probably something to do with InputStream / OutputStream...

The thread that handles the bluetooth connection I/O

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(ControlActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(ControlActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: as you mentioned, it probably has to do with the input/output part. Why don't you post the code relevant to that part? I'm sure you can unit test the code you posted and see for yourself that it is not the part that causes the issue.

Comment: Is rMessage the variable data in the first snippet?

Comment: Some problem with encoding/decoding. Use `String rMessage = new String(rBuf, charset);` and pass the proper charset for decoding the message.

Comment: Can you provide the rMessage value that fails?

Comment: rMessage is ##:##:##:##:## , where ## is any integer value 0-100, the *only* .setProgress that doesn't work is when I am parsing the value of split[4] to set the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the rMessage is having some characters at the end like a EOL character or something else.

If you don't want to spend time debugging that `you could add a ":" to the end of "data"` instead,

```
String data = String.valueOf(seekBar1.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar2.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar3.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar4.getProgress()) + ":"
            + String.valueOf(seekBar5.getProgress()) + ":";
```

This way, your `split[4]` would still be proper and only the `split[5]` will be invalid which you are not going to use anyway.

Comment: I did this, but it ended up causing another issue with something else, haha